# knitr: edit ggplot object when processing the document

Tags: r, ggplot2, knitr

I would like to create a theme for all ggplot objects in R markdown. Hence, is it possible to tweak the chart output, e.g.

````
```{r}
ggplot(cars, aes(speed, dist)) + geom_point()
```
````

to add a theme when processing the document, e.g. `ggplot_obj + theme_bw()`?

I have looked into knitr hooks (http://yihui.name/knitr/hooks), but I can't figure out how to use it in combination with ggplot objects.

Thanks!

Comment: you can use `theme_set(theme_bw())` in a first invisible chunk.

Comment: @baptiste I'm just stealing your answer below because I want this question to be marked as answered, and I hope you do not mind. Next time please write it as an answer even if it is just one sentence :)

Comment: @Yihui but comments are so much easier, I don't have to scroll down to write them!

Comment: @baptiste Laziness understood! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `theme_set(theme_bw())` in a first invisible chunk.

Comment: Also worth noting: set `cache = FALSE` for that chunk if one is using caching in the plot chunks